# Sitecore Analytic Reports is not showing results on the CD server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-analytics

I have a CA - CD environment. My analytics reports are showing up on the CA environment. For exp the report for latest visits is showing results on the CA server

When I try to run the same report for latest visit on the CD server it does not show any records.
Sitecore Analytics is up and running for CD. I have check that by running select queries on the analytic database and it has records for latest visit.

I am not sure what I am missing or what configuration changes I need to modify in order to get the reports working for the CD instance

Sitecore Version 6.6 
enableAnalytics="true" />

Comment: Did you set the database to use web instead in Sitecore.Analytics.config on CD?

Comment: Yes the EmailReportTask uses the Web database.

Comment: Have you checked this?http://www.sitecoredevelopment.com/en/MarkGraber/2013/June/Tips-on-Setting-up-a-Content-Delivery-Server-with-No-Master-Database.aspx. Also any error messages in the log?

Comment: Yes, I checked it out the , the setting points to the Web database
<setting name="Analytics.DefaultDefinitionDatabase">

Comment: Why are you trying to run the reports on a CD? That defeats the purpose. You should collect visitor data on the CD and run the reports on the CA instance. What you're trying to do is not standard practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that somehow the TrafficType table on CD was missing data in Production. The Visit data was been tracked correctly, but since the Dashboard reports works off a join with the TrafficType table no reports were showing up on CD.